# We have voting to close, move to other sites, why not a vote set as community wiki?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Close as community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5871/close-as-community-wiki)
>   [Add a vote to convert a question to community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29592/add-a-vote-to-convert-a-question-to-community-wiki)

Why not have a vote to make something community wiki? And conversely a vote to NOT make something a community wiki? Seems like a better choice than the vote to close alternative now.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: Closing and CW are **not** alternatives. Anything that should be closed as a non-CW question should probably also be closed as a CW question, with *very* rare exceptions.