# SO is too eager to turn my edited answers into Community Wiki

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, edits, community-wiki

I like to edit my answers. To clarify, illuminate, add examples, add links, point to new information as it crops up, etc.

It's highly irritating that my effort to improve my answer turns it into a Community Wiki.

Could anything be done to keep me from turning into a collective?

Comment: Heh... 9 edits, the last 6 each made within a half-hour of the previous edit (one 6 minutes after the previous... two minutes faster and it'd still be yours). You should really consider either editing a lot faster, or a whole lot slower!

Comment: Yeah. Clearly my timing sucks.

Comment: I've decided to deliberately not care when my edits push me CW.

Comment: I'm going to force this post into Community Wiki :)

Comment: You don't have to. I'll eventually do it by accident.

Comment: And I just did this on SU.....sigh.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46078/quick-edits-force-a-badly-formatted-post-to-wiki-within-minutes

Comment: it also makes sense, since you're likely editting your answer because of comments from the community

Comment: Is some circles, it is called the "community wiki of death". FYI.

Comment: I only found out about this after my edits turned my post into community wiki. I understand the reason but where's the trust for established users?

Comment: Four years and no one has replied to the last paragraph with "Resistance is futile"?

Comment: [This no longer applies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947).

Answer (score 82):

I concur with this one; edits from the original author shouldn't count towards community-wiki-ness.

Comment: Utterly disagree. The idea is to stop people bumping their question to the front page constantly, and gaining rep via this. Auto CWiki'ing is a reasonable disincentive to this

Comment: Then, surely, the question shouldn't get bumped to the front page as the result of an edit.

Comment: @dbr then address the issue of bumping directly instead of using a weird side effect penalty.    Two ways to solve this are only re-bumping if a significant time has passed since the last edit,  or simply limit the # of times it can be bumped.   Or, remove the bumping entirely (which I don't like, often legitimate edits make a question answerable)

Comment: What if there are _no_ _other_ _answers_ at the time of the edit?  How can it possibly be unfair to anyone if those edits did not count towards wiki-nature?

Answer (score 63):

Someone just pointed out in a comment that [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285723/c-for-a-c-developer/285819#285819) has been CW'ed. Now I'm not so much of a rep whore that this really upsets me, but it seems counterintuitive, as it effectively punishes me for making my answers better. In this case, it seems a bit unfortunate that I apparently disowned an answer with 87 upvotes. (my third-most repped answer)

I understand the rationale for turning the post CW after X edits, but it seems a lot of good answers get caught in the crossfire.

A couple of possible modifications to the rules could be:

- After the first N edits, **instead of turning the post CW, just stop bumping** it when it gets edited. I generally edit my posts when I become aware of errors or flaws in the answer. I don't care about getting the post bumped, I just want to make my answer better. So you could just stop bumping them once they reach the N-edits threshold.
- Use some kind of **heuristic** to determine whether this is *"an attempt to bump the answer",* or of it is a genuine edit. A lot of edits in a short time (say within an hour or two) seems like genuine improvements. And if a *really* long time passes between edits, people probably aren't trying to game the system by bumping their posts. Most likely, they received a comment or similar, which made them re-read their answer and update it. But if a post is updated every few days, or every week, it might be suspicious. Of course getting such a heuristic right might be tricky,but at least you've got plenty of test data to experiment with. ;)
- Look at how much previous edits have bumped the question. Editing a question which is already on page 1 of the Recent list probably isn't an attempt at getting it bumped. Editing one which has fallen further behind is more suspicious, so that might count towards CW-ificiation. Or perhaps look at how much time has passed since the last activity in that thread. If someone else edited another answer 5 minutes ago, which bumped the thread, then that makes it likely that I simply rediscovered the thread, read my answer, and decided to make a few improvements. And the effect of my edit is almost nil, since the thread was already bumped those 5 minutes earlier.
- Or perhaps simply add a checkbox when editing: "Should this cause the answer to be bumped?" iF the user checks this, the thread gets bumped, and he gets one strike against his CW limit. Keep doing this and it gets CW'ed. If he unchecks it, the edit is made, but the thread is not bumped, and it doesn't count towards CW-ification.

Just a few ideas. This seems like one of the few cases where SO actually discourages positive behavior. I tend to edit my posts quite a lot, and I think that's a good thing. My answers are better than they would be otherwise.

Comment: Except for the first one these are all really great ideas!

Comment: +1 Especially the last bullet point. Offer a choice between bumping & increasing the CW strike count, or not bumping.

Comment: Just FYI, apparently you can flag your answer to ask a moderator to un-CW it. Just in case you're interested, and haven't done it yet.

Answer (score 29):

The reason for having the questions/answers automatically going into Comunity Wiki status, was to prevent people from editing Their question/answer just to bump the question to the first page.

The only thing is, it doesn't really solve the problem, you could just go edit someone else's answer, and it would bump the question up. Or add another answer to the page, perhaps with a dummy account, and have it edit it's own answer repeatedly.

I personally would prefer it **not bumping**, to it becoming a Community Wiki.

---

If anybody wants to know where this rule came from, it was discussed on [podcast #20](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/podcast-20/). I have included the relevant portion of the [transcript](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W24222).

**Atwood**: -

> Somebody wrote a bot that would just
> revise posts every minute to keep it
> on the top of the stack. Actually
> there is a certain amount of people
> doing that still, which I'm trying to
> discourage. They way I like to
> discourage things is, where possible,
> creating rules in the system that make
> that behavior not desirable. Not
> negative, necessarily, but things
> happen that make it not worth much to
> you.
>
> So let me give you a specific
> example in that scenario. You have the
> user who's just editing their own
> posts every three hours so that it's
> always on the top of the stack. We
> have this concept now, it's actually
> implemented though I talked about it
> in previous podcasts, of the community
> owned post. Because one of the great
> divides in StackOverflow is that we
> have this ownership system where you
> get voted up and down, your content
> gets voted up and down, and that
> affects your reputation. You own
> stuff, so when you post something you
> own it. Then you contrast that with
> the Wikipedia model which is that
> nobody seems to own it, and we're
> trying to do both of those things.
>
> At
> the transition point we came up with a
> couple rules. The initial rule I had
> was that edits by four different
> people will cause a post to switch
> from being owned by Joel, for example,
> to being owned by the community user.
> At that point you don't lose any
> reputation that you got up to that
> point, but any future upvotes on that
> content don't go to anybody they go to
> the content. I think this is the way
> it should be. Ultimately you're voting
> on the content more than the person
> anyway, so hopefully people are ok
> with this.
>
> Seeing that people kept
> editing stuff over and over I bent the
> rules a little bit and said ok, if you
> edit your own thing more than N times
> then it also becomes a community owned
> post. There is no real value to the
> user, in terms of getting additional
> reputation, to bump stuff up to the
> top of the stack anymore because if
> you edit your own thing enough you
> won't get any reputation from it. It
> behooves you to only edit it once, or
> however many times you need to edit it
> but hopefully no more than once, and
> just let it sit there and have people
> find it organically and naturally the
> way it is supposed to happen.

Comment: That is basically what I just wrote...

Comment: You can only bump using other people's posts if you have over 2k rep...which the vast majority don't.

Comment: Why not just stop bumping minor edits... say, less than 20 characters changed.  That allows for typo corrections, while still having an effect for material changes to a question.

Comment: @Soft you can put a lot of spam in 20 characters.

Comment: @Earlz: What does that have to do with bumping the question, community wiki, or anything else in this post?

Comment: @Earlz What spam can you fit into 20 characters?  What does spam have to do with whether or not a post gets bumped?

Comment: @end @soft in 20 characters, you can replace two link references with bit.ly links. Looking back on this now. Maybe just not bump unless there is a link changed or added?

Answer (score 13):

I edit compulsively. I doubt there's any post over a few paragraphs in length that I haven't edited *at least* a half-dozen times.

And yet, I can't remember a single instance where I've accidentally triggered CW mode. Indeed, before SO put the checkbox on the edit screen, I struggled at times to force answers I *wanted* CW into CW mode!

See, I edit in spurts. A big change, followed by several small changes as I proof-read. And all that happens within the 5-minute grace period, so most of them don't even show up in revision history (much less the more lenient CW trigger).

So, my advice then, is... **save up your edits. Make 'em count**. Open a text editor, and make your changes while you're researching, then submit them en-mass. Not only does this reduce the chance that you'll inadvertently trigger CW, it provides those reading the front page with more of a reward for clicking through to see what changed when the question gets bumped by your edit...

Comment: I've hit it by accident. At least a warning would be nice so I'd know how close I was getting.

Comment: I think it took me about 8 or 9 edits to turn one of my answers to wiki. I'm not sure what the threshold is supposed to be.

Comment: Yeah... I've wanted to make a new CW-faq for a while now, but really have no clue what the exact behavior is anymore. It's plenty hard to trigger accidentally with my workflow, that's for sure.

Comment: I was a magazine editor. I can edit an answer as many times as I can edit a code file. :-)

Comment: My advice is pretty much identical to this: rather than editing a hundred times for tiny stuff, make 4-5 edits that **really matter**. It's a saner behavior for the entire system.

Comment: What a bad answer, why not just say "work around the system's bugs"?

Comment: @Evan: because that doesn't actually offer *anything* to *anyone*. Such a trite answer dismisses the problem and mocks the asker, implying that the former was well-known and the latter already had a solution but was unwilling to make use of it... It brings to mind the "just use jQuery" answers posted to Prototype questions, or the "just use Windows" answers on Linux posts - rude and unnecessary. Small wonder then that **your** answer similarly proposes discarding the entire platform instead of attempting to make it work...

Answer (score 11):

I edit like crazy. If my answer reaches the top of the list, I edit even more. There is always *something* I forgot to add, something that could have been said better, a sentence best followed by a code example or refinements based on comments.

While I usually refrain from editing other people's posts unless some glaring error remains after leaving a comment to point it out, I edit my own religiously. I've been nailed by the same thing a few times, actually I became rather upset the first time. I'm at 9k something now, I'd be well over 10k if I actually earned the rep from every up vote.

I really don't care about rep anymore. Well, sure I do *care*, but not to the point that I won't correct or add something to make my answer better, even if it means not seeing a number on a web page increment.

Due to having my site in my profile, I've actually received *email* regarding some of my answers, not just comments, especially on controversial topics. Make edits when you need to correct or augment something, even if it means your score at the top of the page doesn't increment as much as it would. The *answer* is what matters, if you care enough to edit in the first place.

Besides, you still earn badges.

Answer (score 11):

Kaveh [brought up some valid points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199252/146126), points I've been considering for a while during some thoughts I've had on community wiki.

> 1. it doesn't seem to be very effective in preventing too many small edits,
> 2. it is abusing a feature which seems to have been designed with a different goal and using it as a punishment,
> 3. it has side-effects like reasonable edits over reasonable periods of time causing a post to become CW.

1 isn't as much one I follow as much as, it didn't do much *about* too many small edits. It was just "Wiki, we're done here", and that's it. No one is told that it happened, no one is told why it happened, and no one is told what shouldn't have happened. The other two, especially the second, are very much on point about the issue.

It is my pleasure to announce that **we will no longer automatically turn your edited answers to community wiki**. Or any posts at all - all of the automatic triggers in the system have been removed. In their place, we have setup a number of alert flags that are given to moderators in the event of too much revision activity or too much answer activity. The point of these will be to help identify when their is abuse, and have it handled much more appropriately.

Comment: So that's what you were doing all this time! :-)

Comment: @Shadow Only one part of it. There will be more to come. ♪

Comment: I'll take your word for that! Any hint of what is coming? :)

Answer (score 8):

My proposal is this:

1. Increase the amount of times the author can edit a post before making it CW. I suggest making this 8 or 10.
2. Edits that are done by the same user(including author) within 5-10 minutes(to taste) within each other are not counted and will not rebump the question.
3. The first 15 minutes a question/answer is posted, none of the edits count.

1 will help with improving answers/questions as more research is done. 2 will fix the minor-edit problem for whenever you make an edit and then discover you misspelled something, and then after discover your formatting is a bit wrong. 3 will fix the problem for when someone posts a poorly formatted question on a popular topic and 6 people edit it at the same time.

Answer (score 5):

The reason this is in place, if I remember correctly, is to prevent people form endlessly bumping their posts with edits.

I agree that it is a pain though.

Comment: So it could be fixed by not bumping me up if I edit too much.

Comment: I agree with that suggestion.  After a certain number of edits, the post should just stop bumping.

Comment: I would prefer it not bump me up, than for it to go into CW status.

Answer (score 2):

Not bumping through edits would prevent sediment churn, which means old (and possibly wrong) information would be left to fester and die in the bowels of the system -- unseen and unloved. That's much more toxic to our community than someone sacrificing a few reputation points.

Our CW threshold is quite generous; I suggest adapting your workflow to do fewer, larger edits instead.

Remember: getting good information out into the world, and getting answers, are the real goal, not arbitrary points -- so we have to favor processes that further that goal.

Also, being a hybrid system, we have *aspects* of wiki (information-first) and traditional bulletin board / blog (owner-first), but there's always a tension in balancing those aspects of the system.

Comment: But what if you opted for what seems to me to the best of both worlds?  I would suggest you allow editing to bump up until the point where it meets the current criteria for being converted to CW, then it stops bumping but does not convert to CW.  Perhaps that flag could then clear again after a set amount of time, although I don't know if that's necessary.

Comment: Could you instead just limit the # of edits that create a bump?  Or put in some sort of rate limiting?

Comment: Jeff, I'm a bit surprised that you haven't implemented a rate limiter for this.  You're already doing this for votes and other parts of the system; but churning a detailed post into a CW that's permalocked is a bit harsh to the poster; it's like saying "we're rewarding your hard-won effort with a slap".  A rate limiter would solve the issue entirely and prevent the kind of question/answer churning that causes bumpage.  If you have delays between each edit, or exceed a number of edits in a given timeframe, there is a cool-down that would be required before you could save the edit.  Simple.

Comment: The same person editing a single post can turn it into CW? I think that's ridiculous. What about a "single" person coincides with "community"?

Comment: This idea breaks down on SF and SU where a user is troubleshooting an issue.  The process you recommended was for the owner to edit the original question as more troubleshooting is completed.  Doing that eventually causes the owner to change though.

Comment: @dlux I disagree -- we've done a *ridiculous* amount of troubleshooting / editing in this question and it isn't wiki yet. http://serverfault.com/questions/104791/what-does-it-mean-when-arp-shows-incomplete-on-eth1

Comment: Could you please add a warning when this is about to happen? I had no idea editing your own answer to clarify some points would turn it into Community Wiki. I wrote a script, which was the original answer, then I made updates with notes and examples of the script's usage. I don't feel like those kinds of edits should push someone's answer into a Community Wiki status.

Comment: Also, to rebut your comment about "arbitrary points". I would typically agree with that statement, however much of the site's features depend on accumulation of these "arbitrary points". Good answers will earn points naturally based on their merits. Why punish those authors who make meaningful edits in order to make their answers better? Shouldn't you want to *encourage* this behavior, and reward it with more site features?

Comment: This seems very much at odds with your usual policy of encouraging good behavior. Usually, rep is not "arbitrary", but is an important carrot to encourage us to make the best possible Q&A site. Here, someone has pointed out a real problem in the rules, which *discourages* good behavior (I *want* to improve my answer, but I don't dare do it after the first couple of edits, because I'm tired of my answers being CW'ed). It may not be a problem for you, with your workflow, but for some of your users it is a problem. Are you saying those users should just stop improving their answers?

Comment: How about, instead of just going by *your* experience, look at the data (as you've done in so many other cases). How many answers are "auto-CW"'ed due to excessive edits by the author? If you sample a few random ones, do *any* of them seem like attempts to game the system? Do any of them seem like "bad" edits that should be discouraged? If not, why does the system currently in place discourage it? There are so many possible improvements that could be made to the system, to *both* prevent people exploiting edits to bump their answers, and *also* avoid punishing people for improving their answer

Comment: I'm surprised you propagate this as a means *against* unseen “old (and possibly wrong) information”, while in fact you *discourage* people from updating and possibly correcting that information. This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. If you want “sediment churn”, then don't punish the ones doing the churning.

Comment: Why not just stop bumping after ten edits? Or stop bumping from that specific user's edits? The auto-CW trigger seems needlessly punitive, since the user's behavior isn't known for sure to be undesirable.

Comment: As it stands taking time to research and make good answer will not give the most reputation. Why? because people come by, see a semi decent answer, up vote it (even if it wrong, but it appears to be good at first glance) and then they are gone for good. Because of that the initial answers my get three times more reputation than one that comes two minutes letter that better, more complete, or just plain correct. A similar problem happens with down votes to questions. They come, see there is a problem, down vote and are gone for good. Even if the problems are fixed, they don't come back.

Answer (score 2):

I just accidently triggered the auto community wiki by editing my answer to this question:

[What should I know to select a power supply?](https://superuser.com/questions/18099/what-should-i-know-to-select-a-power-supply/)

I just wanted to point out other good points from other answers even though mine was accepted as the answer. I guess i should have just used comments. And you cannot even rollback.  I guess I know from now on and there is no way to reverse it.

Comment: Yeah, those would have made a lot more sense as comments... Oh well. Now that you've made it CW, i can edit in links to the answers you're responding to... ;-)

Comment: Too bad. You lose. :-)

Comment: i did lose

Comment: on the contrary, you have *won* knowledge .. of how the system works!

Comment: @Jeff: Honestly, I could strangle you for these snotty comments on this particular topic. I am confident that you will "see the light" on this one eventually, like you did with meta... though it totally escapes how you cannot have groked this already... :(

Comment: @Oliver.. and your comment will be deleted in 3....2....

Comment: @OliverGiesen: Maybe he doesn't want to make this change to the source code because he's already edited it 9 times...

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering, now that CW for questions has become a mod privilege shouldn't we also update this automatic triggering?

I understand the problem that Jeff refers to but it seems to me that it is not a good way of preventing too many edits:

1. it doesn't seem to be very effective in preventing too many small edits,
2. it is abusing a feature which seems to have been designed with a different goal and using it as a punishment,
3. it has side-effects like reasonable edits over reasonable periods of time causing a post to become CW.

Can't we come up with some other way of discouraging too many small edits? E.g.
how about limiting the number of edits a user can perform on his own posts over some period? in a way similar to limits on the number of questions a user can post?

Comment: This should be a question, not an answer. Ask a new question referring to this one and asking to have the debate reopened. You might also choose to strengthen your argument with some research and statistics (using [data](http://data.stackexchange.com/))

Answer (score -1):

I think we should continue to leave the CW bumping. The system works fine as it is.

I have seen quite a few instances where people abuse the system with editing and bumping, and if the system didn't automatically change the post to CW, they would gain a lot more reputation for this abusive behavior.

Comment: So, in other words. If it didn't bump the page, they would have **no** incentive to do that?

Comment: No incentive to do *what* precisely?

Comment: Make it auto CW

Comment: Are you sure? I mean if I intentionally bump a really bad question why should this automatically mean that anyone would upvote it? Just because it's the first item on the front page?