# Answer turned to CW, votes pre-CW era doesn't count in tag specific stat

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, community-wiki, statistics, specialist-badge

My understanding is that if an answer becomes CW (one way or another), original author gets to keep the votes pre-CW.

Does this also keep the pre-CW vote count for the tag-specific stat? It doesn't look like it, because I checked recently and suddenly my number dropped. It looks like the tag-specific stat just counts votes for non-CW answers, and doesn't "discriminate" between the pre-CW and post-CW era. If it's eventually CW, then it simply contributes 0 votes.

I'm fine with the fact that my answer became CW (in this case, through the question having 30+ answers), but I would like to keep the votes I earned before it did for the tag stat.

Otherwise I think the system is "broken". Someone can go posting 30+ answers to questions where Jon Skeet answered, and all of Jon Skeet's answers would become CW, and he'd then be 0 at all tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make all votes on answers that earn reputation count towards tag stats & specialist badge total](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29823/make-all-votes-on-answers-that-earn-reputation-count-towards-tag-stats-speciali)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, theoretically, but wouldn't the fact that one guy or gal posted 10+ "answers" to a question be .. noticed? And some kind of action taken?

Anyway, it's [status-bydesign] from my perspective; we're trying to reward activity in tagged questions that *aren't* discussions, and any question which legitimately gets 30+ answers is IMHO by definition a discussion and should not be eligible.

Comment: To provide context, here's the question and my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076078/check-if-at-least-2-out-of-3-booleans-is-true/ - it has 26K views in just 2 days, so somehow it became quite popular, and people just post their own answers, often duping other people's answers, etc. All these "answers" (some of them ARE discussion and not really answers, some are "answers" but in unrelated languages, etc) forced the question and my answer to CW. I'm "fine" with that, but like I said, I'd like to keep everything I earned before this happened if possible.

Comment: The only way this sucks is if you spend a considerable amount of time refining and expanding an answer, thus editing yourself right into CW. On an answer that gets 30+ votes prior to that happening, its nice to keep those votes toward the tag count. Still, really a corner case, its only happened to me once.

Comment: @Tim: I'm actually quite paranoid now that anybody can do things like (i) gang edit my answers to force it to CW (ii) flood a question with tons of mediocre "answers" to force the question and all answers to CW (iii) even with no malice, people may correct typos here and there in my answers and they will all eventually become CW

Comment: @polygenelubricants - I've never experienced anything like that in the fifteen or so months that I've been using SO. If I did, I'd report it. The question revision history would make such abuse rather obvious, no? Inserting and correcting typos, lining up the `=`'s in code snippets (one edit at a time) .. I can't think of ways to do that to someone without being really overt about it.

Comment: @Jeff: so do I "owe" the system a [Great Answer] badge now, because my answer which was 100+ voted pre-CW now becomes CW? That's how it works if the answer is deleted, right? Obviously this isn't deletion, but perhaps for badge calculation CW is the same as deleting it? Just like making it CW is effectively a deletion for tag stat calculation?

Comment: @Jeff: also since it's all CW now, I guess it's in the spirit of SO/CW for me to just incorporate bits of everyone's answer into "mine", right? "Stealing" answers has always been allowed (the point is to get the best answers, period), but in CW mode it's perhaps even more encouraged?