# Conversion from CW to non-CW state?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, community-wiki

The question is short and simple. Why can't Community Wiki posts(specially questions) be rolled back to non-Wiki state?

P.S : Recently my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) was made CW (by mistake I guess) so I was wondering if something like that(conversion from wiki to non-wiki state) could be implemented. Its merely a feature request.

**EDIT** : This feature should be available only to moderators.

**EDIT** : I don't know why this issue became polemic. People started thinking that I have `over inflated` opinion about myself etc. So it would be better to leave everything (posts, threads etc) the way it is. We have got better things to do, right?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? To prevent low-rep users editing, to try and win rep for upvotes, something else?

Comment: @Rup : A moderator can make a post CW **by mistake** (sometimes) but he cannot roll back the post to its original state.

Comment: @Prasoon, do you have an example of a moderator ever making such a mistake? They are very careful about CW, precisely because they know it's a serious change.

Comment: @Popular Demand : Yes I have a very recent example. See [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70242/should-c-faq-tagged-threads-be-made-cw) thread for more details. Moderator [Will](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will) certainly made a mistake(he wasn't aware of the `faq` tag system).

Comment: @Pop Corn I think the thought pattern is that the linked question was made mistake, [if this earlier thread is any indication](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70242/should-c-faq-tagged-threads-be-made-cw).

Comment: Ah, context. Thank you both. (@Grace because OPs get notified anyways.)

Comment: @Downvoters : Leave a comment stating the reason for your downvote.

Comment: @Prasoon: I think voting on meta.SO has more of a poll than it has on SO. So when your feature-request is down-voted, that's someone saying "I don't wan this feature".

Comment: @sbi : Oh I see. But the feature request makes sense. Even a highly reputed member Kop wants it. :)

Comment: I don't think this feature is that difficult to implement. Is it?

Comment: There would be an issue with tag badges as only non-CW votes count to the score. So if a question (and hence answer?) was made CW and then non-CW how do you easily count which votes count?

Comment: @ChrisF : Its simple. The votes(generating scores only) would count from the point when the post gets converted back from wiki to non-wiki state and the votes wont generate any score when its in the wiki mode. Where lies the problem?

Comment: In fact I was wrong - when a post is turned CW, the pre CW votes don't count towards the tag badge any more [see here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54554/59303). While this is about posts turned CW by having 30+ answers, the same logic applies.

Comment: I have very little inclination to support anyone who writes " __Moderators!! Are you listening?__ " As Jeff once said, [there are a few requests in the queue in front of you](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=requests).

Comment: @Prasoon, who said I never supported this? I have edited my answer in an attempt to clarify. But not listening to people who disagree with you is also not a good sign.

Comment: @Popular : Sorry if you feel offended. It was not my intention.  Yes you are right but its just a matter of agreement. People agree/disagree with what you say and there's nothing you can do about it. `:-)`

Comment: @Popular : I have written ` Moderators!! Are you listening?` to make sure moderators dont miss the post and the answers given :)

Comment: Ironically, that message doesn't actually help attract attention. Anyone who sees that line will already be reading the post. Rally support and upvotes for your post, then you'll get better attention. But being vocal isn't really going to do much.

Comment: @Popular @Grace : As as matter of fact you are right. Removed that stuff. :)

Comment: @Prasoon Your questions/answers are no more or less important than anyone else on this site.

Comment: @R.Bemrose : Sorry? I didn't get you. Which post/comment of mine made you feel like that?

Comment: @Prasoon: I could name several, but I'll concentrate on the least obvious: "Yes I have a very recent example. See this thread for more details. Moderator Will certainly made a mistake(he wasn't aware of the `faq` tag system)"  What tag system?  I've never heard anything official or unofficial about said system until this entire incident started the other day.  Under the current system, all tags are created equal (except for the status tags on Metas).

Comment: @R.Bemrose : I don't have any such opinion of myself. I know I am just a beginner in the field of Computer Science. Do I need to know anything more about myself? If yes please enlighten me.

Comment: @R.Bemrose : I take my words back if you feel those were offensive. :-). But please answer my last comment. What makes you feel that I have a `massively over inflated opinion` about myself? :(

Comment: @Prasoon: You want more examples?  How about this one: "I have written  Moderators!! Are you listening? to make sure moderators dont miss the post and the answers given :)"  Do you not think they read all the questions?  As I recall, Meta has considerably more mods than the normal sites for this very reason.

Comment: @R.Bemrose : But I deleted that thing didn't I. However this issue has become a bit extra-controversial. So it would be better that moderators leave everything as it is `:)`. I am happy with my post with community wiki state. No further comments from my side.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As was found in [the question linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/faq-undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points), moderators are only human, and as such, they sometimes fail. That's no surprise and to be expected. However, *since moderators are humans and can make mistakes, they should have the ability to undo them*.

I see no harm in allowing moderators to do this, because

1. Normal, untrusted users won't have a chance to exploit this, since it needs intervention by a moderator.
2. Moderators already have god-like power and can wreak havoc on their site. If we wouldn't trust them to use their abilities sensibly, they shouldn't be moderators in the first place.
3. If they ever flipped the CW flag to `false`, and this would turn out to be a mistake, it could always be flipped back to `true`. That's different from the way it is now: they can flip it once, and this was in error, then currently there's no way to undo this.

In short, the only drawback I see would be that it needs to get implemented. The advantage is that it would help to remedy errors.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a trivial change, if we start flipping a question back and forth reputation gets more complicated.

For example CW ... 1 upvote, mod turns it to non CW 1 upvote, mod turns it to CW.

We will need to end up doing a partial rep recalc for the all users involved, something that is not a trivial change and not implemented on a per-question basis.

Comment: I *knew* there was a mechanical aspect to it!

Comment: It doesn't have to be trivial to do this. As I've written, the idea is to remedy mistakes. It's not like this would be needed several times a day. Only moderators could do it and that makes it _very_ unlikely they will flip it back and forth.

Comment: @sbi, all I am saying is its not easy ... and it will allow moderators to rewrite the past in a way they can not now. Its not an impossible change, just a fairly fiddly one

Answer (score 3):

Because this capability hasn't been implemented. But I think it should, it's very useful sometimes.

**EDIT**: obviously, for moderators only.

Comment: Yes and that's why I have tagged it `feature-request`. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is well-established as an intentional feature. One source is [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741):

> ### Miscellaneous
>
> - There is no way to reclaim your post back from Community Wiki mode. This is to prevent exploits and gaming of the system.

That aside, you can't roll back from CW because it doesn't make any sense. The meaning of CW is "a post that is owned by the **entire community**." How can one user justly take ownership of content that has been edited by numerous users?

EDIT:
Based on the comments, people seem to think I'm terribly against this, which isn't actually the case. The first part of the answer just points out that this has been considered before; it's not a show of approval or disapproval for the earlier decision. The second part was only supposed to be an argument against this feature for the OP, not mods, though I can see how it's a bit ambiguous. Now that the question has been edited, it's no longer relevant.

Comment: That's technically justification as to why there's no community process for reverting Community Wiki. While I have no opposition to the lack of it, there's still no statement on why diamonds, who are otherwise trusted to speak as the stead of the full community, cannot revert it.

Comment: @Grace, you post an answer and make it CW. I add a lot of stuff. It gets reverted to non-CW status. Why do you suddenly have ownership over all that great stuff I added?

Comment: Counterpoint: I post a 500 bounty on a question. You answer with an excellent post intending to earn that bounty, or at least half of it should I forget to award it. Why do I get to reclaim the reputation spent and cancel the bounty? The answer is **I don't**. The ability to recall bounties has just as much potential for exploitation and gaming as the ability to revert Community Wiki, and makes exactly as little sense to do. So a reason for why moderators can do one, but not the other, would have to be rooted in something else (say, mechanical difficulties in tracking).

Comment: @Popular Demand : Check out the edit.

Comment: @Pop You don't gain rep for edits on regular posts either.

Comment: @radp, I never mentioned rep anywhere.

Comment: @Pop: «Why do you suddenly _have ownership_ over all that great stuff I added?» Rep gain is the primary consequence of post "ownership."

Comment: @radp: Right, but for a regular answer, I'd just add my own answer instead.  In fact, I commonly do just that if I have something to add that hasn't been posted yet, **but not if what I'm saying is related to something someone already posted as community wiki**.  In other words, CW promotes different editing behavior.