# Reputation, Tag score and Community Wiki

Tags: discussion, reputation, community-wiki, tag-score

I am aware of the rules regarding tag badges, this is not about them.

I recently converted a number of my old answers to Community Wiki. It appears that a consequnce of this is that I lost some tag badges, that's easily solved.

When something becomes CW reputation earned up to that point is maintained but new votes have no effect on reputation (non tag badges for up/downvotes are still earned though).

In respect of tag score, when something becomes CW all points are lost no matter when they were earned.

This seems to be the only place on SE where things are lost due to retrospective actions why is this ?

Comment: Sounds like a [tag:feature-request] to change it (or at least I think it should be).

Comment: Or even a bug...

Comment: Why is it the only place? When an account gets deleted you might loose points due to the votes that get deleted in the process. If a post gets deleted you also might loose points.  If something is retagged you also will change the score in the tags. // @MarkHurd The current behavior seems more consistent with the tooltip than the alternative so I doubt it is a bug.

Comment: @quid: Retaging shifts the points elsewhere they are not lost. Reputation is not lost when a Q/A is made CW it just makes it such that none is lost/gained from that point forward. Reputation that has been held for more that 60 days is not lost ( I doubt you remember the kerfuffle that caused that rule to be implemented). Anyway as you seem to have missed the point and don't seem to be an employee you can't answer the question anyway.

Comment: I am not sure why you think that I missed the point. Is it or isn't it correct that you *might* loose points when an account is deleted? And, further, that this if it happens it is a loss due to a retrospective action? Moreover, since the *number* of tags on a question can *decrease* due to retagging it seems to me there could be a (global) loss. It is true I cannot answer the question, which is why I did not answer it.

Comment: Since it is still not clear if I got the point or not, I am not sure this info is relevant but just in case http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54554/answer-turned-to-cw-votes-pre-cw-era-doesnt-count-in-tag-specific-stat Basically this question seems like a duplicate to me.