# Reputation limit and tag medals

Tags: support, tags, reputation, badges, daily-reputation-limit

In the last couple of days I had a chance to be quite active - and since I was "tantalizingly close" to reaching the 400 upvotes (silver medal) limit on my C tag, I thought I would focus on those questions. I reached the "200 rep" limit (plus some extra from accepted answers), but found my "tag counter" stuck at 398.

This seems odd - not only do upvotes not count towards reputation (OK, I get that) but they also don't count towards tag count (even though I had gained a lot of today's reputation from other tags).

Is this intentional, or accidental? Is it possible to rethink that behavior?

A related (but different) question was asked before: [Make all votes on answers that earn reputation count towards tag stats & specialist badge total](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29823/make-all-votes-on-answers-that-earn-reputation-count-towards-tag-stats-special) . That dealt with the loss of specialist points when an answer is converted to CW; I'm talking about not getting "specialist" credit, especially when I am contributing to multiple tags in a day (i.e. it's not like all my upvotes for today were in the C tag).

As a compromise proposal, one might say "no more than 200 points rep, and no more than 20 upvotes counted towards a single tag, per day." Rather than "and nothing you do after that counts - except accepted answers".

Note that the current system discriminates mostly against people who get theirs points onesy twosy - many answers with just handful of upvotes per answer. Not sure if that is considered to contribute to SO (it clears many "marginal value" questions up), and whether it should therefore be encouraged or not.

Looking forward to a discussion about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tag votes are completely independent from the reputation cap.

However, the tag score is only updated once every 24 hours (and sometimes the script times out, it did night before last). Be patient, you won't see the badge turn up before the score counts have updated.

If you are impatient, use this excellent online script to gather per-tag scores from the API; these *are* up to date: http://jsbin.com/azeqec/12.

This script takes URL parameters; with your Stack Overflow user id filled in as http://jsbin.com/azeqec/12?sitename=stackoverflow&userid=1967396 I see:

> ```
> tag   score   answer count
> c     402     151
> ```

so you should get your shiny silver badge tomorrow. Congratulations!

Comment: Hurray. Thank you for clearing that up, and for the good news...