# 12 edits make an answer community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is there any point forcing a post to Community Wiki after 6 owner edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/is-there-any-point-forcing-a-post-to-community-wiki-after-6-owner-edits)
>   [SO is too eager to turn my edited answers into Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki)

All edits are made by the same person, i.e. the answer.

I would like to know the reason behind that.

Comment: While it was a much stricter threshold back then, [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333/is-there-any-point-forcing-a-post-to-community-wiki-after-6-owner-edits) covers those grounds, as does [the transcript in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki/8662#8662). In essence, because editing provides bumping functionality, this is a stop-gap to prevent abusive minor edits for the purposes of bumping to the front page for reputation.

Comment: If you have really good reason to do all those updates feel free to Flag your post for moderator attention (after it was made CW) explaining this reason and asking to change it back to ordinary post. After this change, it won't become CW again.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, thanks. I will give it a shot.

Comment: @Dante - I see you were successful? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5402818/revisions Or is it not CW because you deleted and undeleted it?

Comment: @Shadow Deletion/undeletion does not have an impact on Community Wiki status. It's likely that a flag worked.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, yes, it worked. Thanks again.

Comment: [This no longer applies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's part of the auto-community wiki mechanism (see [related FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741)): any post edited 10 or more times by the author converts to community wiki. It's there [to prevent gaming the system for reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki/8662#8662) (*h/t Grace Note for providing source in the comments*), as every time you edit a post, it bumps the question back to the top giving it and its answers more opportunity for more votes.

Comment: h/t? I could surmise the "t", but I'm drawing blanks on the "h".

Comment: @Grace [hat tip](http://www.blogossary.com/define/hat-tip/). My original answer had some speculation that the reason was to prevent gaming; when I submitted the answer I then saw your comment with the source that it *is* the actual reason.

Comment: Ahha. I apparently need to know more people who wear hats, haha ♪

Comment: I am a little bit obsessive compulsive, and I edit my post whenever I find some typos. It seems a bad practice here, which I thought was good....

Comment: @Dante substantive edits that improve the clarity of a post is good; minor edits that fix typos are annoying and don't really add a whole lot of value, particularly because they bump the question to the top of the heap. One thing to keep in mind is that you have a five minute window from the point you submit a post or ann edit where subsequent edits don't count *per se*: they'll all be added to the original post/edit. So make sure to give your edit a once-over after submitting it to make any additional quick changes before the five minutes are up.