# Community Wiki punishes users for improving their posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, community-wiki

> Posts enter community wiki mode when... the post has been edited ten
>   (10) times by the original owner. - [What are Community Wiki
>   posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

Good users occasionally edit their posts to add new info, correct bad info, update the status, fix typos, etc. Many users make legit edits for legit reasons and end up getting their post locked into Community Wiki, ensuring they do no receive reputation for their improved post. A high edit count is more indicative of a user's editing habits than it is of the quality of the post. Can anything be changed to prevent the system from *punishing* users for *improving* their posts? Is there a better way to prevent gaming the system by edit-bumping posts?

> Voting on a community wiki post (up or down) does not affect any
>   user's reputation.  - [What are Community Wiki
>   posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

This post is similar to [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki), but there are a couple reasons this should not be closed as duplicate:

- That question was from 2009, and can be considered localized in time
- Many upvotes were received since that was declined (now +60), begging the issue be reconsidered
- The problem hasn't been fixed!

Comment: What do you propose?

Comment: *"Many users make legit edits for legit reasons and end up getting their post locked into Community Wiki"* ... if the edits truly are legit, it takes nothing more than a mod flag to have it undone.

Comment: @Bart, don't mods have better things to do than fight against the broken system?

Comment: The two main ways for a post to become automatically CW are: "The body of the post has been edited by at least five (5) different users.", "The post has been edited ten (10) times by the original owner". This is not a low threshold. And passing it tends to mean that the post isn't all that great to begin with.

Comment: I'd like to see some figures on how often a CW by self-edits actually happens @trav1s. I don't see it being a frequent occurrence.

Comment: If you edit your own post on 10 separate occasions, it's a pretty good indication that there's something wrong with the post. Note that from any single edit there's a 5 minute grace period where you can edit as many times as you like without them counting towards being CW'd, so you really have to work on getting the 10 edits.

Comment: *"passing it tends to mean that the post isn't all that great to begin with"*, @Oded, or: sometimes means one likes to keep a solution updated to newer releases and all. (For which, indeed, a moderator could step in to remove the CW.)

Comment: If all the edits were made by the exact same user then, yes, CW does not make a lot of sense.  It isn't clear if that's actually the case here.  If the post needs that much work then it would be common for other users to edit as well.  YMMV.

Comment: @Bart according to [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/128135/list-of-questions-edited-by-their-owner-at-least-10-times) we're talking about mere 1470 such questions, many of which I randomly sampled with exactly 10 have been unwikified already.

Comment: @trav1s why not? Like I said, many of those have been flagged and became ordinary posts again by a moderator. Examples: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7280421/447356) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7496779/447356) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12234457/447356) all edited 10 times yet not Comminity Wiki.

Comment: @Bart, If there was a button that deleted the entire website, but it had only been pushed once, would you also argue to keep that button? The number of times this has occurred is irrelevant. There are more intelligent ways to prevent edit-bumping.

Comment: @trav1s: "don't mods have better things to do than fight against the broken system?" As a matter of fact, we don't.

Comment: Preventing edit bumping is not the only reason that this happens; I don't know why you keep pretending like it is. And perhaps more intriguingly, you keep saying that there are "a bunch of better/obvious" ways to prevent edit bumping, *without actually suggesting any*.

Comment: @CodyGray, I'm not pretending... What are the other reasons for turning a users post to CW after he/she edited it 10 times? If you want some alternatives, many have already been posted here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki

Comment: @trav1s I'm sorry, but that's an utterly ridiculous analogy. You're talking about a mechanism that is in place for a certain reason, part of which has been stated in the comments you've put into your question before. And to add to that, it's easily undone for those few cases where it happens. And seemingly it's no burden to moderators. I've never heard them complain about it. I see no reason to change anything really.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks for that. So, not a big (or an actual) problem indeed it seems.

Comment: @Bart, people tend to downplay problems until they happen to them personally. In that case, why be so contrarian? Whether the CW'ed user realizes what happens and begs the moderator to fix it, or if he doesn't realize what happened at all, its still a punishment and inconvenience, regardless if it happens once a year or once a second.

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree @trav1s. Looking through the frankly relatively short list of posts it happened to, in many cases the users seem to have had their posts unwikified. So no problem there. And in most cases I've gone through, I think the wake-up call wasn't such a bad thing to happen to them. I see no problem that needs fixing.

Comment: I don't understand the negative response here. Quite frankly, I was about to put in a feature request myself to remove the automatic conversion to community wiki on edits of answers. It seems to cause nothing but frustration to those who run into it, and I've fielded at least three flags in the last week asking for us to step in and revert wiki status. I don't think this function serves much of a useful purpose anymore, and I'd be all for getting rid of it.

Comment: @BradLarson Virtually every time I've seen a post with enough edits to be wikied the vast majority of the edits were *very* minor, usually over a short span of time (just long enough to pass beyond the grace period).  Sometimes the editor was trying to bump the post, sometimes they weren't, but in most every case they still would have been better off combining the several iterative edits into a single more substantive edit, and having their post wikified (even if reverted) was the indication to them that they should change their behavior (which they did).  That seems like a working system.

Comment: @BradLarson, its negative vote impetus. People see the negative score, enter the discussion with a bias against the OP and support the contrary viewpoint. Please dont let this stop you. I am sure if you can learn something from this and post an improved version, you will get a better response, as a respected member.

Comment: @Servy, people may be changing their behavior to adapt to the system, but not in a good way. They are not improving their posts when they know something could be improved, since they will be punished.

Comment: @trav1s I have never seen or heard of someone ever choosing not to include important information in their answer because they feared the post being made CW, ever. As has been shown, very few people have ever hit the limit, and most all of those that have have learned that they can have it un-wikied if their edits were truly warranted.  Do you have any evidence to support your claim of significant amounts of lost information? Were the limits for wikification much lower; on the order of ~3 edits, I'd completely agree, but at 10 it's so high as to simply not be an issue for almost any legit user.

Comment: @Servy - Most people aren't even aware that this automatic conversion happens. It doesn't act as a deterrent for people abusing edits (which is something that very rarely occurs), but is an annoyance for many people who try to keep older canonical answers up to date. The ratio of times that automatic wiki conversion serves any useful purpose to the times where it annoys well-meaning people trying to improve their questions and answers is not very favorable from what I've seen. Even though it's relatively infrequent, if it has little positive impact, why should we keep doing it?

Comment: @BradLarson I realize the intentional malicious behavior is rather infrequent, but there is still a fair amount of unintentional undesirable behavior in which people are making lots of tiny edits every 5-15 minutes over the course of several hours in which they're building up a large post.  It would be better served to have the post built up just once and then submitted, and this behavior encourages that.

Comment: @Servy, I just got CW-locked for the first time yesterday, and even though I was able to get a mod to unlock it, I lost 80 rep in the time it was locked. So its not like the mod workaround makes everything all better. I didn't even know about the limit, and was making innocent, legit edits. Furthermore, this feature does very little to prevent edit-bumping. If you make just 1 post per day, you can edit-bump posts 9 times per day. You just have to adapt your bot to not go over the limit. So it does *nothing* for abuse prevention and is a *complete hassle* for everyone involved.

Comment: Here is the post I am referring to, so you can see that the edits do indeed add new information, correct bad information, fix diagrams, etc. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/78337/which-way-does-electricity-power-a-circuit/78343#78343 I don't mean to cry over spilt milk here, I'm just pointing out why this is a problem. Obviously, I'm not the only one who has run into this. Also, the burden of proving this feature doesn't prevent info loss is on *you* since you are defending the feature.

Answer (score 11):

The bar is set at 10 edits from the original owner, which is a pretty high threshold in the general case. It is relatively rare that this threshold gets passed on a post.

Note that you tend to see skewed data on Meta. No one comes here to report that the feature is working just fine, that they edited their answer a typical 3–7 times and it did not automatically convert to community wiki. The only people who come here and complain are those who have experienced a relatively unusual problem. You can't necessarily take this as evidence that the issue is rampant and the system is broken.

Remember that there is a completely legitimate, built-in workaround: [flagging the post for moderator attention, explaining what happened, and asking them to remove the community wiki status](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373). Once this is done, the post will not be automatically wikified again.

Comment: `No one comes here to report that the feature is working`... actually, I have done that. :)  (but I agree, it's not the common thing to do)

Comment: Paragraphs 1&2, a bad feature, rare or frequent, is still a bad feature. Paragraph 3, having a mod intervention workaround doesn't make it OK. You have to ask yourself, what is the purpose of this feature? Is it to prevent gaming the system by edit-bumping posts? There are better ways to solve that than placing an arbitrary edit limit.

Comment: @trav1s: yes it's to prevent bump abuse. Why don't you edit your question with these "better ways to solve that"? At least that would be constructive.

Comment: @Mat, "better ways to solve that" is what the answers are for. My question already is constructive.

Comment: @trav1s: your question isn't one, it's a statement. In that case you should be the one proposing stuff. If you had a question rather than a "this must be changed" _demand_ with no suggestions, then yes you'd probably get answers with suggestions from people who agree it should be changed, and rebuttals from people who think it works ok.

Comment: @Mat, I changed some demands to interrogatives, just for you.

Comment: @trav1s: now you can tag this discussion and you're good to go.

Comment: "The only people who come here and complain are those who have experienced a relatively unusual problem." if this were true, then by definition no problems raised here are ever substantial. I hardly believe that to be the case.