# Is the rule "Edits must be at least 6 characters" still in place?

Tags: support, edits, bump

I found a post that is being bumped by the OP (so far 4 times in the last 30 days) by doing meaningless edits: deleting 1 character / adding 1 character. I think that the system has a rule to prevent this. Is the rule "Edits must be at least 6 characters" still in place? Does it depend on the user's reputation or if the user is the OP?

[image]

Comment: *Suggested* edits must be 6 characters at least. Editing your own posts is not subject to the rules of suggested edits.

Comment: Related: *[SO is too eager to turn my edited answers into Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki)*. But it [no longer applies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits/228947#228947) (changed in 2014).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The author of a post has never been limited by the character limit on edits; the limit only applies to *suggested* edits.

Of course, behaviour like this is discouraged, and a good reason to contact them via a moderator message. I wouldn't suspend immediately; on some other websites this behaviour is quite common and we should give them some time to learn which rules apply here.

Comment: So if you see this behaviour please use a custom mod flag on the post to alert the moderator team.