# Do edits in the 5-minute grace period count as edits towards community wiki status?

Tags: support, community-wiki, grace-period

It's clear from [the faq about cw](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) that 10 edits by the author makes a post community wiki.

There's also a 5-minute grace period on editing such that multiple edits in that period don't create multiple points in the revision history.

How do these edits interact with the CW-triggering edit count?

If I edit 3 times in the grace period, does that use up three edits towards CW, or just one?

(Related: [why there's a CW-triggering edit count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14397/dont-have-your-edits-to-posts-you-own-contribute-towards-making-the-post-commu) - partly to stop you bumping your question too often)

Comment: No, they don't. At least not in my experience. They are not counted as three edits, but one.

Comment: @Pekka I think it's being counted *somewhere* (seen a mod or dev here mention something about it) but you're right, not being full revision it won't affect CW status.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update:** (as suggested by Shadow Wizard)

As of [April 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/187824), edits no longer cause a post to become community wiki.

> If I edit 3 times in the grace period, does that use up three edits towards CW, or just one?

No.

Simply you can see the question revision. The revisions (edits) you see are actual edits which get counted for Community Wiki.

For example: [see this revision](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/14397/revisions). Here you can see total 4 edits. (And 3 edits by OP.) This does not include grace period.

Comment: As of April 2014, edits no longer cause a post to become CW: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/152859. (better mention this in this answer.)