# Does editing a question push it to the top of the main questions page?

Tags: support, questions, bump

When I edit my question, does that push it back to the front/top of the list on the questions page?

Comment: Yep, have a look at this question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-to-get-attention-for-your-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: And, before you start gaming the system: that system is watching you -- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35563/auto-community-wiki-by-original-author-is-not-soo-stupid-after-all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the home page, yes.

On the questions page, only if sorted by Activity. Maybe on Hotness. Not if sorted by Newest.

Comment: plus one for random's edit

Comment: yeah, I would +1 your answer, random, but well...