# How to refresh a question on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits

Is it acceptable to refresh/re-ask a question if you have some new details?

If so, what would be an acceptable way?

Do I just edit the post by adding details (let's assume I don't want to put up a bounty)?

If there is no answer at all, is it OK to bump a question via a minor edit? If so, what would be the time limit - a day, a week, never?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can edit your question, and adding new information, as Oded reported.

The question is bumped on the front page also when a new answer is added, or an existing answer is edited.

If you really want to give more attention to an existing question (whenever it is a question you asked, or somebody else asked), you can offer a bounty for the question.
Re-asking a question that has been already asked has just the effect of getting the new question closed as duplicate of the existing one, and that happens independently from the user who asked the question first.

Comment: I think the Community Wiki part of this answer may no longer apply - see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228948/215590

Answer (score 14):

Re-asking a question is not acceptable. It will get closed as the exact duplicate it would be.

If you want to "bump" a question, edit it - adding detail is almost always a good thing.

In regards to time limits - there are none that I am aware of.

Comment: How about deleting the first question and asking it again?

Comment: @RomanHoyenko Why? What more would that accomplish than simply editing it with new information?

Comment: @RomanHoyenko: Beware that, once you've deleted a certain share of your own questions, you could get question banned.

Comment: Well, sometimes there is no new information, hard/very specific questions tend to be not answered for a long time, you need to have a subject matter expert there to answer it and it goes down fast, so I am trying to see what's the best way to deal with bumping the question.

Comment: Adding a [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) is an excellent way to gather attention, @Roman.

Comment: I understand the bounty, I gave it out several times (the results were 50/50 though :-) ).

Answer (score 7):

It's perfectly fine to edit an existing question of yours **if you have new information**.

Editing it just to bump it to the front page is frowned upon.

If you want to draw attention to an old question, you'll have to sacrifice some rep and offer a bounty.

Comment: Note: Not frowned upon on smaller sites. On Physics.SE, I sometimes investigate the "unanswered" tab for any neglected questions and bump them. This is encouraged, since many questions pass by unnoticed, regardless of how good they are. WHenever I find such a question, I answer it, or, if I don't feel I have the expertise--bump it.